Is AMD's Adrenaline software available for any Linux distributions?
For the longest time, I had listed to what the undermentioned unanimously purported - that AMD's Adrenaline software is unavailable:



AMD doesn't have Adrenaline for Linux.

Cited from reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/1e2x1a5/comment/ld41ea6.





Can I get AMD Adrenaline running on different Linux distros, especially Fedora?




You cant, there is no linux version.



Cited from reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/14uqb6v/comment/jr8v3pl.





Where/how can I get Radeon Adrenaline software for Linux?




You cant, there is no linux version.



Cited from reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/1gdibfm.





Is there a way to get AMD Adrenaline on Linux mint [...]




Nope [...]



Cited from reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/17s5xyn/comment/k8nl069.





How well does the Adrenalin Software work on Linux regarding gameplay capture?




AMD never bothered to port Adrenaline to Linux.



Cited from reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/wbhybt/comment/ii6wifa.


However, Wikipedia contradicts this, and with citations:



Its graphical user interface is built with Qt and is compatible with 64-bit Windows and Linux distributions.




Unified-Linux Stable release
24.10.3[5] / June 19, 2024 (5 months ago)

This originates at #cite_ref-6, which directs the user to amd.com/en/resources/support-articles/release-notes/RN-AMDGPU-UNIFIED-LINUX-24-10-3.html.


That article certainly appears to refer to Adrenaline, because the image attached is wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=AMD_Software&oldid=1242575636#/media/File:AMD_Software_Adrenalin_Edition_Logo.png:



Consequently, can someone remediate this discrepancy for me by explicitly stating whether it's available in any scenario for any distribution of Linux?
(Lack of) SE Duplicates
superuser.com/search?q=amd+adrenaline+linux returned 1 result, and it was irrelevant.

I've since found reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/1fx1izp/comment/lqnjhqt, which may answer this.

Either AMD has this software on their website or they don't. I don't see a real question here. This, the top comment on the first result in my own search, explains why Adrenaline software is not applicable in Linux: https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/wbhybt/comment/ii6wifa/

@music2myear, the naming scheme at the least is incredibly confusing. Either one or multiple products go by "Adrenaline", "Radeon Software". One of the cited Reddit comments explicitly states that they're separate, without citation, yet Wikipedia conflates them enough times that I can't see how it'd be an accident. I don't know which to consider accurate.

@music2myear, have you not seen that I've already cited that example? I've read that comment.

AMD's drivers have always been a confusing mishmash of brands/names/products. A brand name is not a feature set. Even if AMD offers a product CALLED Adrenaline for Linux (which it appears to do), the answer given in that comment indicates why that will only be a name on Linux, and not a feature set. Regardless all that, this question is outside the topics allowed on this site. We do not help you find software, and we do not judge between disagreeing online sources.

Anyone can edit Wikipedia articles

@music2myear, why not? They're merely the rationale for the question. It's surely on-topic to know whether driver software is available for an OS. I've seen many a topic request the same, even over on SO. This wouldn't be on topic for SE Software Recs, so where would you consider this correct to transfer to?
